# XSLT: Add few Variables to List

Tags: xslt

I am trying to Add a variable to a list from XML using XSTL and create the merged tag but it is not happening.

```
Source XML.

<Result> 
        <Data>
        <Pass>true</Pass>
        <Data> 
                <account> 
                        <accountNumber>1111</accountNumber> 
                </account> 
                <account> 
                          <accountNumber>2222</accountNumber> 
                </account> 
</Result> 

Requirement is that the output tag should have the list with Pass tag value like below.

<Student>
   <accountNumber>1111</accountNumber> 
   <Pass>true</Pass> 
<Student>  
<Student>
   <accountNumber>2222</accountNumber> 
   <Pass>true</Pass> 
<Student>
```

Current XSLT file is giving the list but I am unable to add Pass Tag.

```
<xsl:template match = "Root/Result">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="account"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match = "account">
  <Student>
    <accountNumber><xsl:value-of select="accountNumber" /></accountNumber>
  </Student> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I don’t see where you try to insert the Pass element.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tried multiple ways but didn't work so I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <xsl:template match = "account">
    <Student>
      <accountNumber><xsl:value-of select="accountNumber" /></accountNumber>
      <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::Pass"/>
    </Student> 
  </xsl:template>
```

Update. Since the source data changed this is what you then need:

```
      <xsl:template match = "account">
        <Student>
          <accountNumber><xsl:value-of select="accountNumber" /></accountNumber>
          <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::Data/Pass"/>
        </Student> 
      </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Siebe, it works but I missed one thing. Sry. Actually the Pass tag is inside <Data> tag, I have updated the query.